# DateTime format in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I want to create a line chart by Google Chart API. I want to get data from AJAX method and set data to chart as javascript JSON array, but I have a problem with datetime format inside. Additional, a AJAX data is a string which generated from PHP. I parse returned string to JSON array which I want to set as chart data.

```
 v1 = '{"Date(2023, 1, 1, 20, 00, 00)", ... }'; # returned string AJAX
 v1 = jQuery.parseJSON(v1);

 data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
 data.addColumn({...something else...});
 data.addRows(v1);

 options = { ... };
 chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
 chart.draw(data, options);
```

And I have this error message in console, when I try use `Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)` constructor ([Google "Date String Representation" method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes)) as first element of `v1` array: `Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Type mismatch. Value Date(2023, 1, 1, 20, 00, 00) does not match type datetime in column index 0`

How to prepare datetime in JSON array and Google Chart API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google's "Date String Representation" method only works when you are passing the json to the data table's constructor.

see following working snippet.

the json must be in a specific format, which you can see below,
or here: [Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

however, they use a bad example on their page because they use the `new` keyword in front of the date value, which isn't required.

point being, you must have the json formatted as below, with keys for `rows` and `columns`...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {

  var jsonData = {
      "cols": [
        {"label": "datetime", "type": "date"},
        {"label": "value", "type": "number"}
      ],
      "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)"}, {"v": 1}]},  // = Feb 1, 2023 (month number index is zero-based)
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2023, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0)"}, {"v": 2}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2023, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0)"}, {"v": 3}]},
      ]
  };
  
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
  
  console.log('data table rows', dataTable.getNumberOfRows());  
  console.log('row 1 date', dataTable.getValue(0, 0));  
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

from here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation

> When serializing data using the JavaScript DataTable object literal notation to build your DataTable, the new Date() constructor cannot be used. Instead, Google Charts provides a Date string representation that allows your date or datetime to be serialized and parsed properly when creating a DataTable. This Date string format simply drops the new keyword and wraps the remaining expression in quotation marks:

> "Date(Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds)"